# PHP Get method without?

Tags: php

Hey so im working on a website and one part of it allows you to lookup a user based on their name. At the moment i have it using a $_GET request so the link would look like:
http://website.com/p?name=John+Smith
How would i be able to remove that ?name= because i see alot of sites doing things like:
http://website.com/p/John+Smith
how would i achieve this because to my knowladge their arent any other forum request types only Post and Get?

Comment: Look up url rewriting, pretty urls, mod_rewrite ...

Comment: This is called friendly URLs and can be achieved via htaccess/Apache/Django/Laravel/CodeIgniter, etc. Really, there tons of options. Just pick a framework and read its manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**URL rewriting** is definitely what you're looking to do. It's well worth playing carefully with it but lots of testing is recommended. With great power comes great responsibility!

Most dynamic sites include variables in their URLs that tell the site what information to show the user. The example you provided is exactly like this.

Unfortunately, a cleaned up URL cannot be easily understood by a server without some work. When a request is made for the clean URL, the server needs to work out how to process it so that it knows what to send back to the user. URL rewriting is the technique used to "translate" a URL like the last one into something the server can understand.

To accomplish this, you need to first create a text document called ".htaccess" to contain the rules. This would be placed in the root directory of the server. To tell the server to rewrite a URL pattern, you need to add the following to the file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^p/[A-Za-z\+]$    /p/?name=$1    [NC,L]    # Rewriting rule here
```

The `NC` bit denotes case insensitive URLs and the `L` indicates this is the last rule that should be applied before attempting to access the final URL.

You can do quite a bit with this one rule, but the specifics extend far beyond the space of my answer here.

> https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

I would highly suggest reading that thorough guide to help you on your quest!